# IOS 8 UIMenuController not working

Tags: ios8

I have a view that is a subclass UITextView. I bring up the UIMenuController after selecting a word. I select 'cut'. Nothing happens. The same exact code works fine in IOS 7. I have for debugging purpose included an override for

- (void)cut:(id)sender
  {

}

On IOS 7 it gets called. Nothing on IOS 8. I have check that the first responder is in fact the view in question.  I have added an observer for the 'menuControllerDidShow' notification and checked for 'view.isFirstResponder' to verify this. Any ideas? Thanks

I've subclassed 'UIApplication' so I can intercept the calls to sendEvent and sendAction. What I'm seeing is that when I tap the 'cut' command in the UIMenuController I get a 'UIEvent'.
This event is UITouch object. In the 'UITouchPhaseBegan' I inspect the object and see that it's view is set to a 'UICalloutBarButton' object. At the 'UITouchPhaseEnded' phase the view is set to null. On IOS 7 this is not the case, the view is still pointing to the 'UICalloutBarButton' in 'UITouchPhaseEnded' state. How can I determine why this view is getting set to null? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in 8.3 beta.